# Getting error while configuring extent reports in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

**BaseTest.java**

```
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;

public class BaseTest {
    public WebDriver driver=null;
    public Properties prop;

    public void openBrowser(String bType) {
        if(prop==null){
            prop=new Properties();
            //"user.dir"+"src\test\java\resources\projectconfig.properties"

            try {
                FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\test\\java\\resources\\projectconfig.properties");
                prop.load(fs);
                System.out.println("This is the AppURL-->"+prop.getProperty("appurl"));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\test\\java\\resources\\projectconfig.properties");
            if(bType.equals("chrome")){
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",prop.getProperty("chromedriver_exe") );
                driver=new ChromeDriver();
            }
            if(bType.equals("firefox")){
                System.setProperty("webDriver.gecko.driver",prop.getProperty("firefox_exe"));
                driver=new FirefoxDriver();
            }
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
        }
    }
    public void navigate(String appurl){
        driver.navigate().to(appurl);
    }

    public void type(String email_xpath, String content){
        getElement(email_xpath).sendKeys(prop.getProperty(content));
        //driver.findElement(By.xpath(prop.getProperty("email_xpath"))).sendKeys(prop.get("content"));
    }
    public void click(String locatorKey){
        //driver.findElement(By.xpath(prop.getProperty("button_xpath"))).click();
        getElement(locatorKey).click();
    }

    //finding element and returning it
    public WebElement getElement(String locatorKey){
        WebElement e=null;
        try{
            if (locatorKey.endsWith("_xpath")){
                e=driver.findElement(By.xpath(prop.getProperty(locatorKey)));
            }else if(locatorKey.endsWith("_id")){
                e=driver.findElement(By.id(prop.getProperty(locatorKey)));
            }else if(locatorKey.endsWith("_name")){
                e=driver.findElement(By.name(prop.getProperty(locatorKey)));
            }else{
                reportFailture("Locator NOT found/incorrect locator-->"+locatorKey);
            }

        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            reportFailture(ex.getMessage());
        }
        return e;

    }
}
```

**ExtentManager.java**

```
package com.qtpselenium.core.ddf.util;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Date;

import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.DisplayOrder;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports;


public class ExtentManager {
    public static ExtentReports extent;

    public static ExtentReports getInstance() {
        if (extent == null) {
            Date d=new Date();
            String newD=d.toString().replace(":", "_").replace(" ", "_")+".html";
            //extent
            System.out.println("D:\\selenium_files\\ExtentReports\\"+newD);
            extent = new ExtentReports("D:\\selenium_files\\ExtentReports\\"+newD, true, DisplayOrder.OLDEST_FIRST);
            extent.loadConfig(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"//suite//ReportsConfig.xml"));

            // optional
            extent.addSystemInfo("Selenium Version", "2.53.0").addSystemInfo("Environment", "QA");
        }
        return extent;
    }
}
```

**The Error is:**

```
D:\selenium_files\ExtentReports\Sun_Apr_02_12_50_36_IST_2017.html
org.testng.TestNGException:
    Cannot instantiate class com.qtpselenium.core.ddf.testcases.DummyTestA
    at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:40)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance1(ClassHelper.java:373)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance(ClassHelper.java:285)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getDefaultInstance(ClassImpl.java:126)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getInstances(ClassImpl.java:191)
    at org.testng.TestClass.getInstances(TestClass.java:104)
    at org.testng.TestClass.initTestClassesAndInstances(TestClass.java:90)
    at org.testng.TestClass.init(TestClass.java:82)
    at org.testng.TestClass.<init>(TestClass.java:45)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:422)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:252)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:222)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:171)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_9_10$1.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_9_10.java:28)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_9_10$DelegatingTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_9_10.java:61)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$ProxyTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:604)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:170)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init>(SuiteRunner.java:117)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1359)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1346)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1349)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1200)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1124)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1096)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:236)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:81)
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:29)
    ... 26 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: freemarker/ext/beans/BeansWrapperBuilder
    at com.relevantcodes.extentreports.HTMLReporter.start(HTMLReporter.java:75)
    at com.relevantcodes.extentreports.Report.attach(Report.java:302)
    at com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports.<init>(ExtentReports.java:78)
    at com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports.<init>(ExtentReports.java:195)
    at com.qtpselenium.core.ddf.util.ExtentManager.getInstance(ExtentManager.java:42)
at com.qtpselenium.core.ddf.testcases.DummyTestA.<init>(DummyTestA.java:19)
    ... 31 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: freemarker.ext.beans.BeansWrapperBuilder
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 37 more

DummyTestA 

package com.qtpselenium.core.ddf.testcases;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Sleeper;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.qtpselenium.core.ddf.base.BaseTest;
import com.qtpselenium.core.ddf.util.ExtentManager;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentTest;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.LogStatus;
```

**The class generating the error (DummyTestA)**

```
public class DummyTestA extends BaseTest {
    /*-->Extent report related
     * public ExtentReports rep=ExtentManager.getInstance();
    public ExtentTest test;*/
    @Test(priority=1)
    public void testA1()  { 

         /*-->Extent report related
          * test=rep.startTest("DummyTestA");
        // -->Extent report related    test.log(LogStatus.INFO,"Starting the test");*/
        openBrowser("firefox");
    //  test.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Opened the Browser");
        navigate(prop.getProperty("appurl"));
        //test.log(LogStatus.INFO, "navigated to the URL");
        if(!verifyText("signintext_xpath", "signinText")){
            /*IF we do not want the rest case to stop and want to execute the test case further we can use softAssert
             *After we declare the softassert we need to AssertAll in the @AfterMethod
             *softAssert.assertTrue(verifyText("signintext_xpath", "signinText"), "Text did NOT Matched");
             */
            reportFailture("Text did NOT matched");
        }

        if(!isElementPresent("email_xpath")){
            reportFailture("Email ID field is NOT present");
        }
        type("email_xpath","EmailId");
        takeScreenShot();

        click("button_xpath");
        //driver.quit();
        Assert.assertFalse(false);

    }

    @Test(priority=2,dependsOnMethods={"testA1"})
    public void testA2(){
        System.out.println("testA2 method");

    }
    @Test(priority=3,dependsOnMethods={"testA1","testA2"})
    public void testA3(){
        System.out.println("TestA3 method");

    }
    @AfterMethod
    public void quit(){

    /*-->Extent report related
     * rep.endTest(test);
     * rep.flush();
     */

        /*Below line of code is to assert All the softAsserions
        softAssert.assertAll();
         */
     }
}
```

Comment: in the error there is `Cannot instantiate class com.qtpselenium.core.ddf.testcases.DummyTestA` where is `DummyTestA`?

Answer (score 1):

The real problem was with freemarker.

The line in the error `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: freemarker.ext.beans.BeansWrapperBuilder` - I had an old version of freemarker that did not have the BeansWrapperBuilder class.

This issue has been resolved by adding the jar file for freemarker 2.3.23,

Comment: We don't  know; what exactly he (user3777770) wants to conclude with that, as the same user posted 3 times different answers even though it was not matched with the post. No more answer plz; Instead, edit your question with the latest update.